# Why does this script close immediately even though I ask for input?

Tags: python

I can't get the output in python with this code.

```
import random
die1=random.randrange(5)
die2=random.randrange(5)
total=die1+die2
input=("\nPress the ENTER key to exit.")
```

The black window immediately closes when opened

Answer (score 3):

You are *not calling* `input()`; you are *assigning* a string to the name `input` instead.

*Remove* the `=`:

```
input("\nPress the ENTER key to exit.")
```

Comment: Note that the input will not be saved in a variable this way

Comment: @RUJordan: which is not the point here. The statement is there *just* to keep the window open while the program waits for keyboard input.

Comment: I suspect he meant to use something like: `myinput=input("...")`.

Comment: @RSahu: no, this is a common enough pattern; on Windows the window would close when the script exits, this line prevents that so you can read the output.

Comment: @MartijnPieters. Of course. Only if I paid closer attention to the prompt being used!!

Answer (score 0):

Over here, you are assigning `input` to a tuple, `("\nPress the ENTER key to exit.")`.

Instead, move the equals sign to **before** the `input`:

```
inp = input("\nPress the ENTER key to exit.")
```

Here is your edited code:

```
import random
die1=random.randrange(5)
die2=random.randrange(5)
total=die1+die2
inp = input("\nPress the ENTER key to exit.")
```

Now your input will be stored in the variable `inp`.

Comment: .. but if the program's about to exit, does it matter whether the carriage return is stored or not?  (PS: that's not a tuple, it's a string in parentheses.)